# Beginner Android why is "id" is "Unknown member" with R.id?

Tags: android

I'm sure this is something dead simple as it's my first android app with code (the hello world example I did was just assigning a value to a string in XML).  My problem is when trying to get the reference for my button in my variable then the id as in R.id is not defined?

The compiler error is in a comment in the code below where it occurs:

```
package com.geeksonhugs.simplecalc;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private Button AddButton;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        AddButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
//"Unknown member 'id' of 'com.geeksonhugs.simplecalc.R'"

        //AddButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }   

}
```

XML layout file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/LayoutRoot" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtFirstNum" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:text="@string/strFirstNum" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edtFirstNum" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:text="" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtSecondNum" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:text="@string/strSecondNum" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edtSecondNum" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:text="" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:text="@string/strAdd" 
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtResult" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You haven't build this project yet right? If so you should build it first.

Comment: Are you using packages within packages, or library projects?

Comment: Please include the layout XML file for `MainActivity`. The obvious answer is that you have a typo in btnAdd...

Comment: I did build it.  I am using AIDE (native android IDE)

Comment: It's apparently a bug in the IDE I'm using.  I'm using AIDE which is an Android app.  I ran an option to "Refresh Code Analysis" and it said no errors.  When I select "Refresh Build" howerver it still reported an error (as well as if I tried to "Run" it).

I have another IDE on my device called Terminal IDE (which is essentially a complete Linux command line environment) and it compiled fine.  Sorry, thanks for your help.  Next time I'll try the command line IDE before asking a question to eliminate an IDE problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `R` class is code-generated for you by the Android build tools when you build your project. This means there are four possibilities:

1. You have not tried building the project yet, in which case, try that.
2. Eclipse doesn't think it needs to build the project for some reason -- try Project > Clean from the Eclipse menu (only relevant if you are using Eclipse, of course).
3. There is some bug in your manifest or one of your resources that is preventing `R` from being built. There should be Eclipse error indicators for this.
4. You do not have an `android:id` attribute in your layout, and therefore there is no `R.id` available.

Comment: It's apparently a bug in the IDE I'm using.  I'm using AIDE which is an Android app.  I ran an option to "Refresh Code Analysis" and it said no errors.  When I select "Refresh Build" howerver it still reported an error (as well as if I tried to "Run" it).

I have another IDE on my device called Terminal IDE (which is essentially a complete Linux command line environment) and it compiled fine.  Sorry, thanks for your help.  Next time I'll try the command line IDE before asking a question to eliminate an IDE problem.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by deleting the bin folder and recompiling using the AIDE App.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the xml file you pasted is called main.xml and under layout folder.
And try to generate the R file again.
That may help.

Comment: It's apparently a bug in the IDE I'm using.  I'm using AIDE which is an Android app.  I ran an option to "Refresh Code Analysis" and it said no errors.  When I select "Refresh Build" howerver it still reported an error (as well as if I tried to "Run" it).

I have another IDE on my device called Terminal IDE (which is essentially a complete Linux command line environment) and it compiled fine.  Sorry, thanks for your help.  Next time I'll try the command line IDE before asking a question to eliminate an IDE problem.

Comment: No worries, mate. Talking about IDE, I am using Intellij. I believe there is a linux verion. If you want,You can have a try.

Comment: Thank you, I've gone with Eclipse...as a beginner, it's just the best way to find examples and get help from the community.

Answer (score 1):

For those using AIDE having issues referencing Id, try deleting the "gen folder" located in the bin folder and recompile. The problem is the R.java class did not create a constructor called Id. So deleting the gen folder containing the R.java class and recompiling solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must add **id** to a component in the XML file. Like this:

```
android:id="@+id/buton1"
```

Now can you click mainActivity.java and write code "R.id." you a see hint to write "buton1" and no error of "id"