# Error: Unknown Member Menu

Tags: android, popupmenu

I am trying to create a popup menu, but i am getting this error, saying "unknown member 'menu' of com.popup.trial.R

What should I do?

my xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  
    <item  
android:id="@+id/one"  
android:title="One"/>  
    <item  
android:id="@+id/two"  
android:title="Two"/>  
</menu>
```

and my java:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, settings2);  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());  
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                        return true;  
                    }  
                });  
            popup.show();
        }  
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `R` class is code-generated for you by the Android build tools when you build your project.

- `Clean` your project or `Build` your project

reference : [Beginner Android why is "id" is "Unknown member" with R.id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219298/beginner-android-why-is-id-is-unknown-member-with-r-id)

follow this link for other example. : https://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

Comment: i did it a couple times now. but is everything ok with the codes? i am using AIDE, maybe it is a bug

Comment: yeah, it is my button name

Comment: ohh then your code is perfect nothing error in your code. See my update answer and follow the link