# How to improve my Tic Tac Toe game design?

Tags: java, oop

> i create a text based tic tac toe game in java ,i tried applying some
>   OOP principals but things get complicated.
>
> What to comment and how to comment properly? is it good idea to create
>   two player object?
>
> How to get rid of so many if else statements?

here is my TicTacToeGame.class :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.*;

public class TicTacToeGame implements IGame
{
    private  Scanner in;

    static  Player currentPlayer;

    private static String PlayerInput;

    private String xMark="x";

    private String oMark="o";

    public static boolean isGameRunning=true;

    private  static Map<String,String>grid;

    Player playerOne;

    Player playerTwo;

    private  final String

    a1="a1",    a2="a2",    a3="a3",

    b1="b1",    b2="b2",    b3="b3",

    c1="c1",    c2="c2",    c3="c3";

//Switch player
    public void nextTurn()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method



        if (currentPlayer.getMark() == playerOne.getMark())
        {


            currentPlayer = playerTwo;

        }
        else
        {

            currentPlayer = playerOne;

        }


    }

    @Override
    public  String getUserInput()
    {

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("enter cell:");
        return PlayerInput = in.nextLine();
    }

    //update cell state by updating grid hashmap 
    //
    @Override
    public void updateGame()
    {

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("      1   2   3");
        System.out.println("   A) " + grid.get(a1) + " | " + grid.get(a2) + " | " + grid.get(a3) + "");
        System.out.println("     ---|---|---");
        System.out.println("   B) " + grid.get(b1) + " | " + grid.get(b2) + " | " + grid.get(b3) + "");
        System.out.println("     ---|---|---");
        System.out.println("   C) " + grid.get(c1) + " | " + grid.get(c2) + " | " + grid.get(c3) + "");


    }


    @Override

    //check userinput and game state 

    public  void updateState()
    {

        getUserInput();

        if (isValideInput() == false){


            updateState();

            return;

        }

        grid.put(PlayerInput, currentPlayer.getMark());

    if(isGridFull()&&!isAWin()){

        System.out.println("its a tie");

        updateGame();

        displayGameOver();

        isGameRunning=false;

    }else if(isAWin()){

        System.out.println(currentPlayer.getName()+" wins");

        updateGame();

        displayGameOver();

        isGameRunning=false;
    }

        else{

            System.out.println(currentPlayer.getName()+" ends his turn");
        nextTurn();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void initLogic()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        in = new Scanner(System.in);

        grid = new HashMap<String,String>();


        grid.put(a1, " "); grid.put(a2, " "); grid.put(a3, " "); 
        grid.put(b1, " "); grid.put(b2, " "); grid.put(b3, " ");
        grid.put(c1, " "); grid.put(c2, " "); grid.put(c3, " ");


        playerOne = new Player(); 
        playerTwo = new Player();

        playerOne.setMark(xMark);
        playerTwo.setMark(oMark);

        if (currentPlayer == null)
        {

            currentPlayer = playerOne;
        }
    }


    @ Override
    public boolean isValideInput()
    {

        if (grid.containsKey(PlayerInput))
        {

            return true;

        }

        System.out.println("invalid input");

        return false;
    }

    @Override

    public  boolean isAWin()
    {

        if ((grid.get(a1) + grid.get(a2) + grid.get(a3)).equals("ooo") ||
            (grid.get(b1) + grid.get(b2) + grid.get(b3)).equals("ooo") ||
            (grid.get(c1) + grid.get(c2) + grid.get(c3)).equals("ooo") ||
            (grid.get(a1) + grid.get(b1) + grid.get(c1)).equals("ooo") ||
            (grid.get(a2) + grid.get(b2) + grid.get(c2)).equals("ooo") ||
            (grid.get(a3) + grid.get(b3) + grid.get(c3)).equals("ooo") ||
            (grid.get(a1) + grid.get(b2) + grid.get(c3)).equals("ooo") ||
            (grid.get(a3) + grid.get(b2) + grid.get(c1)).equals("ooo") ||
            (grid.get(a1) + grid.get(a2) + grid.get(a3)).equals("xxx") ||
            (grid.get(b1) + grid.get(b2) + grid.get(b3)).equals("xxx") ||
            (grid.get(c1) + grid.get(c2) + grid.get(c3)).equals("xxx") ||
            (grid.get(a1) + grid.get(b1) + grid.get(c1)).equals("xxx") ||
            (grid.get(a2) + grid.get(b2) + grid.get(c2)).equals("xxx") ||
            (grid.get(a3) + grid.get(b3) + grid.get(c3)).equals("xxx") ||
            (grid.get(a1) + grid.get(b2) + grid.get(c3)).equals("xxx") ||
            (grid.get(a3) + grid.get(b2) + grid.get(c1)).equals("xxx"))
        {

            return true;



        }

        return false;
    }


    public boolean isATie(){

        if(isGridFull()&&(!isAWin())){



            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean isGridFull(){

        if(!grid.containsValue(" ")){


            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public  void displayGameOver()
    {

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("            ===============");
        System.out.println("            ||           ||");
        System.out.println("            || game over ||");
        System.out.println("            ||           ||");
        System.out.println("            ===============");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isGameRunning()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return isGameRunning;
    }

}
```

This is my Main.class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{



    public static void main(String[] args) {


        IGame game=new TicTacToeGame();

        game.initLogic();
```

main loop

```
        while(game.isGameRunning()==true){

            game.updateGame();

            game.updateState();

            }


        }

    }
```

> any advices?

Comment: what's the crash? can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Aide-ide logCat shows nothing, it is useless.is there an  other way for getting stack trace on my phone?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: It isn't a good idea editing a previous question that already has multiple answers. Try restoring your previous question and ask a new one since the answers here are strangely irrelevant to the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your xml file is not properly created. Try the following xml file it will definitely work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:fabview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/main_coordinator_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <!-- your stuff here -->

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff00ff"
    android:src="@drawable/your_png_image"
    android:tint="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried your own codes in my AIDE, and it force closed on startup. So i recreated the main.xml file with your exact other codes and it worked. And don't forget to import your package's R

Answer (score 1):

in **buil.gradle** change

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:design:21.+'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
```

it is because you are using

```
compileSdkVersion 21
```

and

```
targetSdkVersion 21
```

if you want to use design support library version 25 you should use `compileSdkVersio 25` and `targetSdkVersion 25`

and i recommend you to use dependencies like this

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

}
```

because when you using `'com.android.support:design:25.+'`
every time you sync gradle it want to check the last version in version 25.+ and its cause wasting time in sync .

Comment: I changed compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to "25" now i have this problem : Unknown member "main" of 'android.R.layout' so i tried cleaning the project but nothing happened.any solutions

Comment: @Didine try Rebuild Project after Clean and use invalidate Caches. two answer can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219298/beginner-android-why-is-id-is-unknown-member-with-r-id . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884361/what-does-the-invalidate-caches-restart-do-in-android-studio

Comment: Thank you for your help ,i am very  grateful.

Comment: @Didine your welcome . accept  this as correct answer for future help other people .

Answer (score 1):

```
minSdkVersion 14
```

and at values folder in styles.xml

```
<style name="ActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#d55d55</item>
</style>
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml in activity tag:

```
android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme"
```

Answer (score 0):

i thought that there is a link between aide-ide m2repository and the problem that i had so i tried with android studio m2repository and it works, now my project compile like a charm and my app starts without any issues.
I hope that will help somebody else.